# How can I uninstall SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to remove any azure/msonline/sharepoint modules from powershell. However I'm unable to remove the PnP module for SharePoint Online

`Powershell> Uninstall-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2194 char:21
+ ...        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage`

The module is located at:

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Apps\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.psd1`

Not sure what Im missing but perhaps someone can enlighten me. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you try to run 'Get-Module SharePointPnPPowershell* -ListAvailable' on powershell and share output? It seems it might be already uninstalled...

Comment: `Powershell> Get-Module SharePointPnPPowershell* -ListAvailable


    Directory: C:\Users\jescobar\AppData\Local\Apps\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Binary     3.10.19... SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline       {Add-PnPAlert, Add-PnPApp, Add-PnPClientSidePage, Add-PnPClien...
`

Comment: It still shows. Im unable to install any module also. Im starting to think there is something corrupt with PowerShell. I tried to install AzureAD module and it goes through the installation motions, but when i try to load module, it tells me it does not exist.

Comment: this is most likley an issue with not trusting the PSRepository.  I've done in the past is to delete the entry Uninstall-PSRepository -Name PSGallery  ... Register-SPRepository -Default ...  Further, i've seen cases where updating PowerShellGet.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue a few days ago.

What worked for me was deleting the entire "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" folder and then installing the module again using

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been troubleshooting this issue for a couple of days now, so I'll post my solution here even though this is an old question (2nd result in my Google search for the error message). Hopefully, this can help someone in the same situation...

No matter how many times I tried `Uninstall-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`, it always came up as *not* installed.

Searching the standard location for PS modules also didn't help because there was no `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` folder.

I then found the bugger in `C:\Users\<myuser>\OneDrive - <mycompany>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`.
It turns out OneDrive was syncing this legacy module from an old install.

After deleting the above folder I was finally able to `Install-Module -Name "PnP.PowerShell"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name,Version,Path
```

Note the **path** option at the end of the command. With the path, I was able to delete the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline folder.